# Suspicious pointer-to-pointer conversion (area too small)

Tags: c++, lint

I am getting this warning for my logic -

Logic :

```
uint8_t     *m_data;

uint32_t* datap = (uint32_t*)m_data;
```

Warning:

```
Info 826: Suspicious pointer-to-pointer conversion (area too small)
```

As it is required to typecast the value during assignment ..And i am not feeling there is something wrong in given line of code ..how I can suppress this warning or remove it from build

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? If `m_data` points to something that has only 8-bits of space, why would you want to point to it as if it had 32-bits?

Answer (score 2):

That's not a correct cast, you're attempting to interpret a pointer to a byte as a pointer to 4 bytes, and can lead to unexpected results. If `uint32_t` has different alignment requirements than `uint8_t`, you might even get a different value of the pointer, and also what it points to. If you want to convert the value, just do:

```
uint32_t datap;
datap = static_cast<uint32_t>(*m_data);
```

Comment: but then, what if sizeof a pointer is 8 bytes? same problem still.

Comment: @perreal no, not really.

Comment: @Ashwin you can get the address of `datap` if you really need a pointer.