# Suspicious pointer-to-pointer conversion (area too small) in C

Tags: c, pointers, lint

```
uint8_t *buf;
uint16_t *ptr = (uint16_t *)buf;
```

I feel the above code is correct but I get "Suspicious pointer-to-pointer conversion (area too small)" Lint warning. Anyone knows how to solve this warning?

Comment: stop violating the strict aliasing rule, that's how.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552209/suspicious-pointer-to-pointer-conversion-area-too-small

Comment: @Jeff This is tagged C.

Comment: What are you trying to do with that code? It's not possible to say if this is correct or not without context.

Comment: @jforberg it's almost certainly incorrect since he likely dereferences the pointer.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I'll agree that it's likely to be incorrect but there are cases where it could be necessary. Maybe he passes the pointer through an interface which requries the type, but he knows that the pointer type is actually (uint16_t *). Not saying this is good code but in any case the question can not be properly answered without context.

Comment: @jforberg that's true.

Comment: uint8_t *buf is part of the interface so I cant change it.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, don't cast the pointer at all. It changes the *way* (representation) a variable (and corresponding memory) is accessed, which is very problematic.

If you **have to**, cast the *value* instead.

Answer (score 0):

Its a problem in your code

In line **uint8_t *buf***  you must have assigned it with an memory area which is 8 bits long

and then in line **uint16_t *ptr = (uint16_t *)buf;** you try to assign it to a pointer that will access it as 16 bits.

When you try to access with *ptr* variable you are acessing memory beyond what is assigned to you and its a undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule). Imagine that when you have a case like this:

```
uint8_t  raw_data [N]; // chunk of raw data

uint16_t val = 1;
memcpy(raw_data, &val, sizeof(val)); // copy an uint16_t into this array

uint16_t* lets_go_crazy = (uint16_t*)raw_data;
*lets_go_crazy = 5;

print(raw_data);
```

Assume the print function prints all the values of the bytes. You might then think that the two first bytes have changed to contain your machine's representation of an uint16_t containing the value 5. Not necessarily so.

Because the compiler on the other hand is free to assume that you have never modified the `raw_data` array since the memcpy, because an uint16_t is not allowed to *alias* an uint8_t. So it might optimize the whole code into something like:

```
uint8_t  raw_data [N]; // chunk of raw data

uint16_t val = 1;
memcpy(raw_data, &val, sizeof(val)); // copy an uint16_t into this array

print(raw_data);
```

What will happen is undefined, because the strict aliasing was broken.

Though note that your code might be perfectly fine if, and only if, you can guarantee that your particular compiler does not apply strict aliasing to whatever scenario you have. There are compiler options to disable it on some compilers.

Alternatively, you could use a pointer to a struct or union containing an uint16_t, in which case the aliasing does not apply.